# Share file externally via URL in shared folder with SharePoint Online. Like a "shared file playlist"

Tags: sharepoint-online, shortcut, external

I have a library of media assets on SharePoint. When I engage with clients, I create a folder to share with them, and add needed assets to that folder. Rather than duplicate the files repeatedly throughout my document library, I'd like to create the equivalent of a shortcut/alias. A sort of shared playlist, so that I don't have dozens of copies of a single file in my document library.

I know I can force a download of a file by changing the URL to include *web=0*. But when I share that link externally, the .url is accessible in the folder, but the linked file is not. Because of my org settings, I cannot make the original files available to "anyone with the link." If I have to share it from the original asset library, that defeats the purpose of the shared folder and would give the client numerous links to open instead of one shared space.

Any thoughts on how to create a list of links for a client in a single space on SharePoint Online? Thanks for any help!

Comment: I’m not clear about something about your environment:  is your tenant permitting external sharing outside your organization?

Comment: I am able to share files and folders directly with external people to the organization. I cannot set a share link to be available to "anyone with the link."

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint Online is very careful about permissions. If you want to set it to share with anyone, you could manage sharing settings in CA.

See reference:
[Manage sharing settings](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/turn-external-sharing-on-or-off)

Comment: I am not an administrator, and my org will not change permissions to allow the "anyone with the link" sharing.

Comment: Have you considered putting all the files you want to share in the same library and then sharing them with the users you want?

Comment: I have. I'm trying to avoid having to manage permissions over time individually on thousands of files that would be shared out to hundreds of individuals. That's why at this point I'm duplicating the files into a shared folder with each client, so one folder of deliverables can be managed.